# Animated Panel in Java

Tags: java

how do applications get animated such as when you press a button, suddenly this whole panel would slide out then another panel would slide in with another set of option. is it playing with Thread.sleep(time) then change coordinates of the panel? or there's more than this algo?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat general, but let me try. Yes, Thread.sleep(time) is relevant here(http://johnbokma.com/java/applet-animation.html). There is latency as you redraw. Java provides a lot of features in the javax.swing package for that kind of stuff : see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29 . Also, see here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ .

for a simple slide-in/out animation, try this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/SlideinandslideoutanimationSmartGWT.htm .

And Java 2D graphics is pretty broad, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_2D)